# GWT module not detected by IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I'm trying to enable GWT debugging in IntelliJ 14 Ultimate for an old project.

I have enabled gwt support in IntelliJ, downloaded the GWT version that is used by the project (2.2.0) and created a facet that targets that path:

[image]

I set it to target the web facet. I then got a warning about how the gwt compiler output and gwt-user.jar were not part of the artifact so I added them to it:

[image]

As I created the facet I added to the main app module. Finally I created a run/debug configuration where I specified the app module and enabled "User Super Dev Mode" but the "GWT Modules to load" field is disabled.

I built/compiled the project and am not getting any errors however I still can't see any GWT modules in the project Facets or Module sections.

This [JetBrains article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/adding-a-gwt-facet-to-a-module.html?origin=old_help) seems to imply that I should add framework support for GWT however I do not see it as an option when i right click the project>Add Framework Support..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of trying a bunch of different things (updated IDE, change JDK, recreate project, etc) the "culprit" turned out to be my VCS: I copied a colleague's local version and it IntelliJ was able to recognize the GWT module.

I was surprised since I had run multiple pulls (well 'updates' to be more exact since it is Perforce we're talking about) yesterday so I tried a force pull and voila... the modules are now showing:

[image]

Thanks for your replies Vojtech and Thomas!

Answer (score 1):

SuperDevMode was added in GWT 2.5; with 2.2 you're forced to use the legacy DevMode, with browser plugins, which means Internet Explorer or an old Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike support for other frameworks, I cannot see GWT when I right click project root in Project tab and select "Add Framework support".

However, It still works when I select

> Project Structure → Facets → Add → GWT

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vojtek. I can also see GWT in the facets. The issue for me is that, despite configuring the GWT facet and module in the project, IntelliJ doesnt seem to be able to detect that the module contains GWT. "GWT Modules to load" is greyed out in the GWT run/debug configuration and the GWT compiler output is empty

Answer (score 0):

I just had to move the gwt XML, for ex to the folder where client and server folders are. And Intellij recognised it.